# creating session then passing to other function not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiohttp

I want to do a request with a session created in the main function then pass it to the post to do a get request and return the source but its not working

I tried printing numbers every where and it seems to fail to do the request itself which is this line

```
async with session.get('https://google.nl') as resp:
```

```
async def post(session):
    async with session.get('https://google.nl') as resp:
        return await resp.text()

async def check(line):
    while True:
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
            print(await post(session))
```

I am expecting to print the text of the source and i am getting 0 errors

Comment: Do you run the async event loop, [as shown in readme here](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/v2.3.3/#getting-started)? Just in case.

Comment: yes I am doing exactly what is says to do in the docs but its just not sending the stuff

Comment: IDK if it's relevant, but `https://google.nl` is a 301 redirect, what serves the actual page is `https://www.google.nl/`. I wonder if the redirect is followed by default, but I would first make it work with an URL that is known to serve content.